# jQuery - Does jQuery Form Plugin work for IE/Opera/Safari?

Tags: jquery

I have developed my web application that is based on jQuery Form Plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ + Firefox. I use ajaxSubmit to submit the form with all kinds of components including FILE.

Is there any issue that those application may break with IE/Opera/Safari?

This question is specific to the adoption of jQuery Form Plugin.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any known issues I'm aware of with the form plugin, it's widely used and actively supported...when a cross-browser issue pops up they fix it pretty quickly.

Tthis is one of the advantages of using a plugin, the authors and community have a collective interest in supporting, maintaining and improving it.

*(I'm not advocating a plugin in all cases, but for ajax forms submission it definitely makes sense)*

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem at all.